# Spring boot 2.0 kafka message send error

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

When I use spring boot 2.0，I want to send a message. When I only use one bootstrap-servers it can success, but when I use cluster the message can not be sent, when I use callable I get some error info as follow.

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaProducerException: Failed to send; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.
```

This is my code and config

**Code:**

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class Producer {

    @Resource
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;


    public void send(String topic, String message) {
        log.info("send message: topic: " + topic + " message: " + message);
        kafkaTemplate.send(topic, message);
    }

    public void send(String topic, String key, String message) {
        log.info("send message: topic: " + topic + " key: " + key + " message: " + message);
        kafkaTemplate.send(topic, key, message);
    }
}
```

**Config:**

```
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=ns016:9092,ns016:9093
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
```

Comment: Just want to make sure you have single host ns016 for two brokers but with different ports 9092 and 9093.

Comment: I have resolved this problem.The kafka is 0.8.2.2 in my server. The error solved when I upgrade.